# Multi language setup not working in WildFly 8.x but working in Jboss 7.x server with JAAS?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, wildfly, multilingual

I am developing jsf multi language application which configured with form based authentication in Jboss 7X /WildFly 8x. In login page I have drop down list to change the language. After login, the labels will be in the selected language, which we selected in login page.

My problem is multi language is not working when running the app with wildfly 8x but it is working fine with Jboss 7x. Is there any configuration differences in Jboss 7x and WildFly 8x for Form Based authentication(JAAS).
I am not getting solution for long time. please help.

Comment: Please read [ask], I almost 100% sure, no, I am 100% sure you won't get any help with questions like this

Comment: And wildfly IS JBoss

Comment: There is no server-dependent configuration for multilingual applications. It is a locale which you maintain in an HTTP session and is bound to `<f:view locale="...".../>`.

Comment: @Kukeltje: Wildfly AS is the new JBoss AS. So he is talking about a problem that did not exist in JBoss AS (7.x) and exists now with WildFly AS(8.x).

Comment: @Sri Please specify the used version numbers and create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and maybe check your post for any missing words...)

Comment: Yes I know, I should have obviously added the question to post version numbers. Sorry... And in even more detail, there also are EAP releases and it could also have been AS 6 or whatever. Posting from a phone often leads to leaving things out

Comment: Make sure you trash any cookies before testing with WildFly after switching of server on very same domain.